# Strange behavior for Google Chrome height animation

Tags: google-chrome, css, animation

I'm trying to use CSS to animate a 'div's height on my site.

It works perfectly on FF and Safari but on Chrome it has a strange behavior.

I have 4 'div's which when clicked they stretch to show the entire containing text then when clicked again they contract and become hidden. On Chrome once I click one of them they ALL expand to full height and then, when the animation ends, return to the height they should be in the first place.

You can see that on : http://www.wefind-tech.com/WhatIsIt_ChromeV.html

Is there a solution for that ?

Thanks

Erez

The CSS is:

```
.WeFind_Div_PunchLine::first-letter{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .WeFind_Div_PunchLine{
        width: 95%;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;

        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-radius:10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -o-border-radius: 10px;

        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #CCCCCC;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #CCCCCC;
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #CCCCCC;
        -o-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #CCCCCC;
    }

    .WeFind_Div_Contructed{
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /*VERTICAL EXPAND element animation*/
    @keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Expand{
        from {height: 0px;}
        to {height: 150px;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Expand /* Firefox */{
        from {height: 0px;}
        to {height: 150px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Expand /* Safari and Chrome */{
        from {height: 0px;}
        to {height: 150px;}
    }

    @-o-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Expand /* Opera */{
        from {height: 0px;}
        to {height: 150px;}
    } 

    /*VERTICAL CONTRUCT element animation*/
    @keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Contruct{
        from {height: 150px;}
        to {height: 0px;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Contruct /* Firefox */{
        from {height: 150px;}
        to {height: 0px;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Contruct /* Safari and Chrome */{
        from {height: 150px;}
        to {height: 0px;}
    }

    @-o-keyframes WeFimd_Anim_Contruct /* Opera */{
        from {height: 150px;}
        to {height: 0px;}
    } 

    .WeFind_Div_Expand{
        overflow: hidden;

        animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation: WeFimd_Anim_Expand 1s;

        -moz-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Expand 1s; /* Firefox */
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Expand 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -o-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Expand 1s; /* Opera */
        -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

    .WeFind_Div_Contruct{
        overflow: hidden;

        animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation: WeFimd_Anim_Contruct 1s;

        -moz-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Contruct 1s; /* Firefox */
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Contruct 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -o-animation: WeFimd_Anim_Contruct 1s; /* Opera */
        -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>WeFind web site, What is WeFind</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/WeFindAnimations.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/WeFind.css">

    <script>
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') window.location = "./WhatIsIt_IEVer.html";

        function ResetAllElement(ElementName){
            var CurentElement = ElementName.substring(0,1);

            for (var Index = 1; Index < 5; Index++){
                if (Index != CurentElement && document.getElementById(Index + '_DivContent').getAttribute('class').indexOf('WeFind_Div_Expand') > 0){
                    document.getElementById(Index + '_DivContent').setAttribute('class', 'WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contruct');
                    document.getElementById(Index + '_DivContentLineExpander').src = "./Images/ArrowDown.png";
                }
            }
        }

        function ToggleExpandContruct(ElementName){
            if (document.getElementById(ElementName).getAttribute('class').indexOf('WeFind_Div_Expand') > 0){
                document.getElementById(ElementName + 'LineExpander').src = "./Images/ArrowDown.png";
                return('WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contruct');
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById(ElementName + 'LineExpander').src = "./Images/ArrowUp.png";
                return('WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Expand');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="WeFind_Table_Stretched">
        <tr>
            <td class="WeFind_Table_CellHorizontalSpacer170px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="WeFind_Table_Cell_PortrateText">
                <div class="WeFind_Div_PunchLine" onclick="ResetAllElement('0_DivContent');">WeFind, A community obligated to create a safe living environment for all.</div>
                <div id="0_DivContent" class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contructed" height="0px">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

                <div class="WeFind_Div_PunchLine" onclick="ResetAllElement('1_DivContent'); document.getElementById('1_DivContent').setAttribute('class', ToggleExpandContruct('1_DivContent'));">
                    The power of "community bond" and "community commitment"
                    <img id="1_DivContentLineExpander" class="WeFind_Img_LineExpander" src="./Images/ArrowDown.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="1_DivContent" class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contructed" height="0px">
                    The WeFind community utilizes the power of "community bond" and "community commitment" to create a safe living environment for loved ones, the elderly and the challenged, a safe environment for everyone.
                </div>

                <div class="WeFind_Div_PunchLine" onclick="ResetAllElement('2_DivContent'); document.getElementById('2_DivContent').setAttribute('class', ToggleExpandContruct('2_DivContent'));">
                    The power of the masses
                    <img id="2_DivContentLineExpander" class="WeFind_Img_LineExpander" src="./Images/ArrowDown.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="2_DivContent" class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contructed" height="0px">
                    WeFind uses the power of the masses to create a safety net, continuously alert and ready to provide both passive and active assistance to anyone in need. That net is widely spread and instantaneously available. The ability to be where help is needed fast, and the ability to spread  a "Call For Help", enables the WeFind community to provide immediate aid, prevent harm, providing support effectively and instantaneously.
                </div>

                <div class="WeFind_Div_PunchLine" onclick="ResetAllElement('3_DivContent'); document.getElementById('3_DivContent').setAttribute('class', ToggleExpandContruct('3_DivContent'));">
                    Created by a cheap, wearable location sensitive device.
                    <img id="3_DivContentLineExpander" class="WeFind_Img_LineExpander" src="./Images/ArrowDown.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="3_DivContent" class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contructed" height="0px">
                    The WeFind community safety net is created by a cheap, wearable location sensitive device and a mobile phone application. That device is attached to a kid, an elderly person, a challenged child or just anyone you. The device is sending location and status information to the WeFind community datacenter. Based on that location the community is able to receive alerts, when the one wearing the device needs assistance or is lost, and display messages which enable the community to monitor the whereabouts of that someone.
                </div>

                <div class="WeFind_Div_PunchLine" onclick="ResetAllElement('4_DivContent'); document.getElementById('4_DivContent').setAttribute('class', ToggleExpandContruct('4_DivContent'));">
                    There is no safety witout privacy !
                    <img id="4_DivContentLineExpander" class="WeFind_Img_LineExpander" src="./Images/ArrowDown.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="4_DivContent" class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Div_Contructed" height="0px">
                    Data regarding each device is distributed based on the relations between the one wearing the device and the one receiving the information. Close relatives (Father, Mother, etc.' ...) receive detailed information while other people are filtered out. <span class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Text_BodyUnderlined">Privacy is a key element in the WeFind community</span>; it is one of <span class="WeFind_Text_Body WeFind_Text_BodyUnderlined">the main building blocks of maintaining a safe environment</span>.
                </div>

                <p class="WeFind_Text_Body">
                    <center><img src="./Images/WeFind_CommunityHelp.png" width="600px"/><center>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve the problem.

The cause of the problem is a CSS section for the 'table' containing the 'div's.

The table had a class :

```
.WeFind_Table_Stretched{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The height : 100% caused the problem on Chrome.
IMHO a bug in Chrome but I did not manage to get a response from Google on that.

I removed the height 100% section and the whole thing works like a charm.

Erez

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a lot of code to achieve the end result. You may want to look into jQuery's slide toggle feature. http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ This should eliminate the need fo all the css animations and the javascript you have.

In jQuery you could do something like:

```
$('h3').click(function(){
    $('p').slideToggle();
});
```

Here you click on the heading and the p is revealed.

If you do continue to use CSS, you do not need animations, just simple transitions, and you can toggle a class on and off to animate the height. W3 Schools has a demo that I think would help with this. http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Here is a simple fiddle using jQuery with slideToggle. http://jsfiddle.net/markgtoce/HTyXm/

Comment: I tried both options. Still FF is displaying a smooth animation but, Chrome is expanding all the div elements instead of a smooth transition. You can see the effect on the modified version of the page at: http://http://www.wefind-tech.com/WhatIsIt_ChromeV.html all the code is inline (CSS and JQ) so you can see what I did.